# Matplotlib dates as ticks

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I have a plot with dates on the x-axis and some arbitrary numbers on the y-axis.
I want to have an x-tick every second Saturday. This works fine so far with the following code:

```
weeks = matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=5, interval=2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(weeks)
```

I have now ticks at the 4th of July this year, 18th of July, and so on...
But I want to have ticks at the 11th of July, 25th of July, ...

How can I give it an offset of one week?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score -1):

So this might be cheating because I use `pandas`, but I think it works.

```py
import pandas as pd

#get all Saturdays in the range
all_sats = pd.date_range(start='20150101', end='20150630', freq='W-Sat')
#get every other Saturday in the range
eo_sats =  pd.date_range(start='20150101', end='20150630', freq='2W-Sat')
#get properly offset list of Saturdays using a set difference
final_sats = all_sats.difference(eo_sats)
```

Now you can just feed in `final_sats` to `ax.set_xticks` comme ca:

```py
ax.set_xticks(final_sats)
```